# make new column in db table with symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I am working with previously built symfony project by someone and I want to execute a new migrate command to edit and add some columns in a table but I can't execute any migration command.

I write

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

and I see this error

```
There is no column with name "idx_country_id" on table "product_country_vat".
```

I want to add new column without changing anything in structure of another database table
what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: How do tou propose to add a column without changing the db structure?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone to help you. Did you alter the entity/entities in some way before attempting to make the migration? It looks like you might have added an annotation/attribute to add an index but the property you reference doesn't exist? Edit your question and add the relevant parts of your entities

Comment: It sounds like your migrations and your database are not in sync. If your don't have all of the migrations, one option would be to empty your migrations folder, and then run the make:migration again -- that way it will not assume that any intermediate migrations will be run, but rather start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You have one of the migrations in your migrations folder that is trying to do something (delete or change?) with the `idx_country_id` column for the `product_country_vat` table. The problem is that the table does not have this column at the time this migration is performed.
Judging by the name `idx_country_id`, you want to add an index, not a column.

If you want more information, you should provide the migration code